# Tell nginx to use different PHP process on random "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm

On a webserver, that usually works quite well with `nginx` and `php-fpm` (currently version 7.0.22, but this is mostly independet from the version), there are times when a 502 Bad Gateway occurs. This sually means: One of the `php-fpm` processes has crashed, and `nginx` does not receive an answer from the chosen process.

My current **workaround** is to monitor not only the `php-fpm` process, but also the output of a PHP page. And if this does not work for 4 minutes (two failed retries with a surveillance interval of 2 minutes), then `monit` will kill all `php-fpm` processes and restart the `php-fpm` service. Works, but still causes a 5 minute downtime (at least for some users that connect to the broken process) or more, because `monit` may as well see the answer from a sane process a few times, before it observes the 502 Bad Gateway.

(1) The ideal solution was to bugfix whatever break the `php-fpm` process. Yet, the error occurs rarely, so I was unable to track it down to some specific reason. Possibly a memory leak in a PHP script ... I don't know.

(2) The second best option, I have in mind, would involve some cooperation from `nginx`. If the webserver process could react to a PHP failure, it could (a) kill the specifically broken process and (b) try another process instead of throwing the 502 Bad Gatway.

So far, I did not find an option to make `nginx` react to the failure. Who has an ideas how this could be achieved? Or is there an easier solution, I missed?

```
connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** move the request from one process to another inside the same upstream, but you **can** move it from one upstream to another.

**First of all, you need at least two upstreams (you will need two different php pools):**

```php
upstream yourproject {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm_primary.sock;
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm_secondary.sock;
}
```

**Then you can configure the failover between them:**

```php
location ~ \.php$ {
    # First, you need to capture fastcgi errors
    fastcgi_intercept_errors      on;

    # Specifies in which cases a request should be passed to the next server
    fastcgi_next_upstream         error timeout http_500 http_503;

    # Limits the time during which a request can be passed
    # to the next server
    fastcgi_next_upstream_timeout 10s;

    # Limits the number of possible tries for passing
    # a request to the next server
    fastcgi_next_upstream_tries   2;

    fastcgi_pass yourproject;
}
```

But this is not going to resolve your problem, because you would be doing the failover between the same server.

I suggest you:

1. Use TCP sockets instead of UNIX sockets, they are more reliable and stable for high concurrency:

   ```php
   upstream yourproject {
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
   }
   ```

   You have obviously point your php to this TCP socket in your php pool configuration (`listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`)
2. Increase process and fd limits `/etc/limits.conf`:

   ```php
   *    soft    nofile    65536
   *    hard    nofile    65536
   *    hard    nproc     65536
   *    soft    nproc     65536
   ```
3. Increase `net.core.somaxconn` and `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Maybe you are reaching the limit.
4. If you are using `pm = dynamic` in your PHP configuration pool, check this parameters and adjust them according to the documentation and your system resources: `pm.max_children`, `pm.start_servers`, `pm.min_spare_servers`, `pm.max_spare_servers`. Maybe you are reaching the limit too.
5. Increase `pm.max_requests` in your PHP configuration to avoid the respawning process occur too often.

If this doesn't work, copy and paste your PHP and Nginx config files, to take them a deeper look.

Comment: That's a brilliant response, thank you! I'll try it immediately. Also thanks for the hint about TCP sockets. I had the idea in mind that a unix socket was more performant (if that's true at all), but stability is a more important issue for my server.

Also thanks for the configuration hints. I'm not yet convienced about no. 5 (if there's a memory leak anywhere, respawning a bit more often should be a good thing), but there are also a lot further hints in your response that I did not consider so far.

Comment: If the secondary upstream should not be used round robin, but only in case of an error, than one can add `backup` to the upstream definition: `server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm_secondary.sock backup;`, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream